# scrollToItem UICollectionView error - index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I run on simulator it works ok. But when I run on physical device, I face an error - `index out of range`. 
**Code:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let index = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath
    resultController?.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

P.S : I want `UICollectionView` to scroll to top when I click.

Comment: The error happens why you try doing what?

Comment: I'm getting a similar problem. Were you able resolve this issue? How were you able to identify where the issue is coming form??

Answer (score 1):

To scroll to the top of the view, use the `setContentOffset` method.

```
collectionView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

Your issue is caused by the collection view's automatic cell reuse, which dequeues cells when they go offscreen. This sometimes results in no cell at the first index, which is the reason for the index out of range error.

Comment: Where in your code do you get the error? Is it in the code you posted in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in my project. It works fine. Please check whether your `resultController?.collectionView?` is right.